# What happens when media queries aren't supported?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Say for example I had this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
     .example {
         background-color: red;
     }
}
```

What if I view this page in Internet Explorer 8? Will it still color `.example` red even though the width is over `480px`, or will it just ignore the stuff in the media query? *<sub>(I can't test it because I don't have IE8 :P)</sub>*

Comment: You can test using IE 8 via: http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried it out in IE7/IE8 browser/document modes (IE10), and it completely ignores **all** CSS inside Media queries for me as I assumed it would do. `.example` turns out with a red background only in IE9+.

The only section in the specification I can find which is (probably) relevant to what actually happens here is the [**Error handling section**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#error-handling).