# What happens if I specify a media query property that is not supported?

Tags: css, media-queries

You have questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158334/what-happens-when-media-queries-arent-supported), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748527/what-exactly-happens-when-a-browser-doesnt-support-media-queries) that say if the browser doesn't support media queries the whole thing is ignored.

What I need to know is what happens if the browser supports media queries, but don't support a specific property. For instance the following would target any devices up to 750px width on portrait orientation. Now, assuming I'm running this on a device that doesn't support the "orientation" property. Would the orientation property be applied to any device smaller than 750px or the whole thing would be ignored?

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:750px) and (orientation: portrait){ 

/*some css rule*/

}
```

Comment: Have you tested this yourself?

Comment: I'd really like to but I don't have access to a device that doesn't support the orientation query (i only know about iphones < 4.12), I don't know how I would test that.

Comment: Then test with a rule that you know the device doesn't support (i.e. a keyword you made up yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748527/what-exactly-happens-when-a-browser-doesnt-support-media-queries):

> If the browser doesn't support Media Queries then nothing happen it's
>   ignore everything inside the condition.

For your questions this means, that if the browser doesn't know one media query (which you are connectiong with `and`) all media queries are ignored. You can test this by "inventing" own media query like this:

```
@media screen and (test: "test"){
    body {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/JVqqd/
As you can see the query is ignored because test is unkown, but it might be a future media query.

@Mr Lister
According to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) no issues regardin media queries are known, so all follow this concept

Comment: The test you exhibit here is persuasive, but the quote from the linked question is irrelevant. Not supporting a *particular* query is not the same thing as outright not supporting media queries, and the quote thus doesn't indicate one way or another what the behaviour in this case should be. This answer would be strictly better, in my opinion, if it started from *"If the browser doesn't know one media query ..."* and everything prior to that was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the device would treat the media feature as if it were unknown, much like how a browser that doesn't support a certain property would ignore any declarations that use it (e.g. Firefox still refuses to recognize `box-sizing` without the prefix).

Essentially this means [the whole thing would be ignored](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#error-handling):

> - **Unknown media features.** User agents are to represent a media query as "`not all`" when one of the specified media features is not known.
>
>   > ```
>   > <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-weight: 3kg) and (color), (color)" href="example.css" />
>   > ```
>   >
>   > In this example, the first media query will be represented as "`not all`" and evaluate to false and the second media query is evaluated as if the first had not been specified, effectively.

Of course, in your case, it's not a made-up media feature like `weight` but one that is defined in the spec, `orientation`.

Comment: I know for instance that old iPhones (<4) don't support it. We're way past that now, and it's great, but I'm a bit concerned that maybe there might be some older version of android that will ignore the query.

Comment: @caiocpricci2: Interesting. There are a number of sources that seem to confirm that ([1](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/the_orientation.html) and [2](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries)).

Comment: According to caniuse iOS 3 partially supports the queries, which makes sense, but android has full support since 2.1. I'm happy not supporting iOS 3 and androids < 2.3.3, so this is not an issue for me anymore!

Comment: This answer is oddly equivocal. `orientation` is an example of a "media feature", so I'd've thought that if a browser doesn't support it, then in that browser it's by definition an "unknown media feature" and that the spec unambiguously requires the browser to "represent" it as "`not all`". Was your concern that a browser might theoretically have distinct concepts of a feature being "unknown" and "unsupported" and handle hypothetical known-but-unsupported features in an idiosyncratic way not dictated by the spec?

Comment: @Mark Amery: Yes; for example, with selectors and properties, some browsers are known to recognize them for the purposes of not invalidating entire selector-lists or cascades, but otherwise treat them as no-ops. I haven't found that to be the case with media features, though.